# Setup Vue.js with Phonegap without using template or framework

Tags: cordova, vue.js, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, vuejs2

I am just a newbie with Vue.js and Phonegap.
Please help me in implementing Vue.js with Phonegap without using any template or framework. Just a simple listing example will do. All help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a template?

Comment: I just want to experiment by using Bootstrap for design and apply Vue.js with it. Is that possible?

Comment: I believe this question has merit. Ionic and others can help a lot with styling and such. But just making a simple html/css/js (could be VueJS or other) app with phonegap can be great for learning step by step, and keeping things clean and light.
I personally love Ionic's tools, only reason I use Ionic (i don't care for the styling, i prefer custom)

Answer (score -1):

Oh, you will need template for speedup ! trust me !

Framework7 with vue is nice to go !
http://framework7.io/vue/

And this is phonegap template, it have hot livereload: 
https://github.com/centrual/cordova-template-framework7-vue-webpack

Check README.MD it easy to understand ^^

Happy coding :))))))))))))))))

Comment: Thanks for answering. But as a newbie I want to experiment by using the resources that I already know instead of learning something else, like for example, Bootstrap for design and apply Vue.js with it. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it possible. If you a newbie you should using playground ide like http://codepen.io

This is my example TODO with firebase, vuejs, bootrap : 
[Click to open app](https://codepen.io/cuduy197/pen/xqPPVe)